# Login to USR9108 router control panel

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, control-panel

Here is the setup: A US Robotics USR-9108 router is connected to an ADSL modem via ethernet cable. The modem, upon connecting with the ISP, provides a gateway address of `192.168.1.1` to the router. End-users including me connect to the internet through the router via WiFi and are assigned the IP `192.168.1.2`...`192.168.1.255`.

When disconnected from the modem, I can access the control panel via `192.168.3.1` but once the ethernet cable is plugged in I cannot access the above-mentioned IP; connecting to `192.168.1.1` opens up the *modem's* control panel. Any possible way to access the router control panel while it is connected to the internet?

Edit: is this called "transparent routing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange to me that your router would provide a range of network adresses in the 192.168.1.xxx range while the gateway you use to access the router is on 192.168.**3**.1 . 
Unless that is a typo, then I would suggest to give your router a different range, something like 192.168.2.1 for the router gateway and 192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.200 for the range of adresses to distribute.

Comment: The router is configured to use the address `192.168.3.1` and assign addresses in the range `192.168.3.2+` to hosts connecting to it. But when its connected to modem it assigns the IP range `192.168.1.2+` and sort of *disappears*... `192.168.1.1` shows the modem login screen.

Comment: @Salman A - Ok thanks for clarifying that. What I now still don't understand is that when I google for 'US Robotics USR-9108', I find an [ADSL Gateway ](http://www.usr.com/support/product-template.asp?prod=9108)(modem + router), yet you only use it as a router with a separate modem?

Comment: Yup. A DSL modem (`ZyXEL P-660R-T1 v2`) was provided by the ISP that plugs into a phone line. To share this DSL connection between 10+ users we use the USR1908 router (we cannot directly plug a telephone line into it).

Comment: @Salman A - This all sounds a bit strange to me, since [this quickguide](http://www.usr.com/support/9108/9108-files/9108-ig.pdf) definitely shows that you can hook up an adsl connection to it. But anyway, what you can try is to turn Global RIP off in the web menu under the LAN tab [image](http://www.usr.com/support/9108/9108-ug/images/scrn_lan_rip.png)But it feels like a long shot.Maybe you can alter your first question with some more details about your setup and the settings of both the zyxel and usr used. (PS: in your last comment, you used 1908 instead of 9108, might confuse other readers.)

Comment: I never realized I could throw away the modem and plug the telephone line into the router, thanks for pointing that out. I'll try that. Configuring ADSL could be a headache but I'll try copying the settings from ZyXEL modem (or contact the ISP if that does not work).

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to access your router wiith `usr9108` then disable DHCP.

It solved the problem for me. Since the Zyxel acts as a main gateway router, Zyxel DHCP is enabled (the one providing ip address to computer). Two DHCP servers enabled on a router make the PC. That's what happens when one router is off: The other gives another gateway and IP address.

You should focus on DHCP when adding a router using a LAN cable. Simple as that.